# No networking in background timer task in Windows Phone 8.1 app running on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

A windows phone 8.1 app is running fine on windows 10 mobile except when it tries to do a http call in a background timed task. The background task is using common code which works fine when the app is active, so the code works, and the requested url also works fine when the app is active.  The http client used is `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`.

I suspect there could be a missing declaration required for windows 10 mobile.

> 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module
>   is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{03B4FAD0-869C-11E4-A292-2935E87BC9D6}\Install\Imatis.Mobilix.BackgroundTask.winmd'. Symbols loaded. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols.
>   Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.THREADING.TASKS.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{03B4FAD0-869C-11E4-A292-2935E87BC9D6}\Install\Imatis.Mobilix.Library.DLL'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.DIAGNOSTICS.DEBUG.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading symbols. Module
>   is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.NI.DLL'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\Data\Programs{03B4FAD0-869C-11E4-A292-2935E87BC9D6}\Install\Newtonsoft.Json.DLL'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .):
>   Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.EXTENSIONS.NI.DLL'. Skipped
>   loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
>   Code' is enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.THREADING.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded
>   'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.PRIMITIVES.NI.DLL'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .):
>   Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.NI.DLL'.
>   Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
>   'Just My Code' is enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .):
>   Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\SYSTEM.CORE.NI.DLL'. Skipped loading
>   symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is
>   enabled. 'backgroundTaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: .): Loaded 'Anonymously
>   Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'.
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in mscorlib.ni.dll WinRT
>   information: The server name or address could not be resolved
>
> The server name or address could not be resolved
>       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at Library.HttpHelper.d__2.MoveNext()

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. Windows 10 Mobile now requires that a `SystemCondition` is added to the `BackgroundTaskBuilder`.

```
builder.AddCondition(new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable));
```

Comment: Thanks, been tracing this issue for weeks. Have an upvote!