# Internet access in a long-running background task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

In my Windows Phone 10 app, I've got a long-running background task, triggered by an RfcommConnectionTrigger. This task will run for as long as my bluetooth Rfcomm device is connected.

Now what I want to achieve is this:

- The Bluetooth device sends some data to the app on the phone (working)
- The phone looks up a value using an HTTP request (not working)
- The phone sends the result back to the Bluetooth device (working)

The problem with #2 is that as soon as I lock the device, all HTTP requests for some reason start failing. I'm just using the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` to do a request, nothing special is going on there. More specifically, the exception is thrown in `HttpClient.SendAsync`.

How do I get around this limitation?

Comment: Could it be something missing in the app manifest? (Just speculating)

Comment: @PedroG.Dias It might be, I'm not sure. What should I be looking for? -- I've got obvious capabilities like "Internet (client)" all enabled.

Comment: What about the background task ones? I did see that background tasks have a total of 30 seconds "wall clock usage" whatever that means - could it be that you're timing out for some odd reason? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks

Comment: Definitely not -- I can launch the app, and as soon as I lock the screen the requests start failing, even 5 seconds in. Also, the error says `Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
WinRT information: The server name or address could not be resolved` which I don't think indicates that the BG task ran out of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I found the solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35685218/no-networking-in-background-timer-task-in-windows-phone-8-1-app-running-on-windo) This seems to be a completely undocumented "feature" -- you need to add a `SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable` condition to your background task to allow it to use internet when the device is locked. I'm hoping that this doesn't mean that when the phone loses internet access, the background task is killed.

It also means that the phone now needs to be connected to the internet in order to start the background task, which is still annoying, but I guess I can live with that.